# hadoop cluster is using only master node or all nodes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I have created a **4-node hadoop cluster**. I start all datanodes,namenode resource manager,etc.

To find **whether all of my nodes are working or not**, I tried the following procedure:

Step 1. I run my program when **all nodes are active** 
Step 2. I run my program when **only master is active**.

The **completion time** in both cases were almost **same**.

So, I would like to know if there is any other means by which I can know how many nodes are actually used while running the program.

Comment: Describe the topology of your cluster and the versions of the components you are using. Describe the program you are running. Describe what have you done to make "only master is active" (which master? NN, YARN RM?). Attach the job logs

Comment: There are 4 DN and 1 NN in my cluster. By "only master is actve", I mean that only NN and 1 DN (on same machine as of NN)of my cluster are "ON".

Comment: Ok, could you now elaborate on what kind of job you are running and its logs with timings?

Comment: There are so many log files .Which log file would you like to see?

Comment: Do you run mapreduce? Can you first attach the stdout you get

Comment: Here is the link for the stdout : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JF7yvk3X13OEpzT3kxaS1rME0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65288/discussion-between-aayush-rathore-and-0x0fff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussed in the chat. The problem is caused by incorrect Hadoop installation, in both cases job was started locally using LocalJobRunner.

As a recommendations:

1. Install Hadoop using Ambari (http://ambari.apache.org/)
2. Change platform to CentOS 6.4+
3. Use Oracle JDK 7
4. Be patient with host names and firewall
5. Get familiar with the cluster commands for health diagnostics and default Hadoop WebUIs